# Python Bit Summation Algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, math, bit

I am trying to implement a function that will be used to judge whether a generator's output is continuous.  The method I am gravitating towards is to iterate through the generator.  For each value, I right justify the bits of the value (disregarding the `0b`), count the number of ones, and shift the number of ones.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from typing import Tuple


def find_bit_sum(top: int, pad_length: int) -> int :
    """."""
    return pad_length * (top + 1)


def find_pad_length(top: int) -> int :
    """."""
    return len(bin(top)) - 2  # -"0b"


def guess_certain(top: int, pad_length: int) -> Tuple[int, int, int] :
    """."""
    _both: int = find_bit_sum(top, pad_length)
    _ones: int = sum(sum(int(_i_in) for _i_in in bin(_i_out)[2 :]) for _i_out in range(1, top + 1))
    return _both - _ones, _ones, _both  # zeros, ones, sum


def guess(top: int, pad_length: int) -> Tuple[int, int, int] :  # zeros then ones then sum
    """."""
    _bit_sum: int = find_bit_sum(top, pad_length)  # number of bits in total
    _zeros: int = _bit_sum  # ones are deducted
    _ones: int = 0  # _bit_sum - _zeros
    # detect ones
    for _indexed in range(pad_length) :
        _ones_found: int = int(top // (2 ** (_indexed + 1)))  # HELP!!!
        _zeros -= _ones_found
        _ones += _ones_found
    #
    return _zeros, _ones, _bit_sum


def test_the_guess(max_value: int) -> bool :  # the range is int [0, max_value + 1)
    pad: int = find_pad_length(max_value)
    _zeros0, _ones0, _total0 = guess_certain(max_value, pad)
    _zeros1, _ones1, _total1 = guess(max_value, pad)
    return all((
        _zeros0 == _zeros1,
        _ones0 == _ones1,
        _total0 == _total1
    ))


if __name__ == '__main__' :  # should produce a lot of True
    for x in range(3000) :
        print(test_the_guess(x))
```

For the life of me, I cannot make `guess()` agree with `guess_certain()`.  The time complexity of `guess_certain()` is my problem: it works for small ranges `[0, top]`, but one can forget 256-bit numbers (`top`s).  The `find_bit_sum()` function works perfectly.  The `find_pad_length()` function also works.

```
top // (2 ** (_indexed + 1))
```

I've tried 40 or 50 variations of the `guess()` function.  It has thoroughly frustrated me.  The `guess()` function is probabilistic.  In its finished state: if it returns `False`, then the Generator definitely isn't producing every value in `range(top + 1)`; however, if it returns `True`, then the Generator could be.  We already know that the generator `range(top + 1)` is continuous because it does produce each number between `0` and `top` inclusively; so, `test_the_guess()` should be returning `True`.

I sincerely do apologise for the chaotic explanation.  If you have anny questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: That is a strange definition of continuity, which is usually defined something like the **differences** between consecutive values being small. There is very little difference between `1.0` and `1-2**-50` but the number of `1` bits is very large. You can say the same for `2**50` and `2**50-1`.

Comment: Interesting observation, @RoryDaulton.  I wasn't sure how to label the idea.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted your `ones_found` assignment statement to account for  the number of powers of two per `int(top // (2 ** (_indexed + 1)))`, as well as a additional "rollover" ones that occur before the next power of two. Here is the resulting statement:

```
_ones_found: int = int(top // (2 ** (_indexed + 1))) * (2 ** (_indexed)) + max(0, (top % (2 ** (_indexed + 1))) - (2 ** _indexed) + 1)
```

I also took the liberty of converting the statement to bitwise operators for both clarity and speed, as shown below:

```
_ones_found: int = ((top >> _indexed + 1) << _indexed) + max(0, (top & (1 << _indexed + 1) - 1) - (1 << _indexed) + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  How did you do it?  How dumb was my mistake?  What was I missing?  How did you find it so quickly?

Comment: @AidanCodeX First I checked the extreme cases- 0b1000... and 0b00...1, and saw the former was off by LARGE amount, and discovered that you need to multiply by 1/2 the power of two you divide by, otherwise you lose that "group". I printed the differences, saw they were now in the low 100s instead of upper 1000s. Then I reasoned I needed to take care of the bit being lost during division, and got it down to differences of <10. I then trial & error'd my way to a difference of zero (I had forgot to add `+1` at the end of `max(...)`).

Comment: I don't think it was a dumb mistake- it took me awhile to get it figured out myself. There were two parts to it- you had to multiply by 1/2 the amount you divided by (after flooring), otherwise you lose all but one of those 1s. Then after accounting for those, you still have to account for the 1s above the largest power of two you account for. That's what the 'max(...)' part does.